# Error 1248 in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1248

I am trying to run this query.

```
select *
from (select *
      from student
      where dept_name= ’Comp. Sci’)
      natural left outer join
     (select *
      from takes
      where semester = ’Spring’ and year = 2009);
```

But every time i get the

```
error# 1248: every derived table must have its own alias.
```

I have tried creating aliases of all the tables that are being derived but same error appears every time.

How can i resolve this problem. I looked up some already answered question but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :::

```
select * from 
(select * from student s where dept_name= ’Comp. Sci’) as tempLeft 
left join (select * from takes t where semester = ’Spring’ and year = 2009) on (// join condition)
```

Comment: Sashi Kant, you forgot about alias for second subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add aliases for subqueries:

```
select * 
from 
    (select * from student s where dept_name= 'Comp. Sci') as data1 
    natural left outer join (select * from takes t where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2009) as data2;
```

Comment: I tried this code but
error code 1054: Unknown column `'Comp. Sci.` in the where clause
occurs

Comment: Did you tried Sashi Kant's variant or my? Sashi Kant made mistake - he forgot alias for second alias.

Comment: Sorry, change symbols ’ to ' (simple single quote)